# Crystal Reports crash in second printing

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I was made to print a report in C#. But I found the error. For the first print run normally. But for the second time, my program is immediately stopped.

The window error is something like that :

> has encountered a problem and needs to close. we are sorry for the inconvenience

The code is :

```
ReportDocument rptDocument = new ReportDocument();
PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();

public void cetak() {
    rptDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/report/fakturpenjualan.rpt");
    rptDocument.SetParameterValue("idpenjualan", idp);

    rptDocument.PrintOptions.PrinterName = settings.PrinterName;

    rptDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
    rptDocument.Close();
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do not reuse the `ReportDocument` object. After you're done using it, call `Dispose` (better yet, wrap it in a `using` block), then create a new one for the next report.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure and DISPOSE the object after closing it and force a garbage collection. The runtime engine has issues if the report object is not completely destroyed.

Comment: _Which_ object? Why suggest "force a garbage collection"?

Comment: John, you're a real piece of work. People like you do not make SO better. You clearly know nothing about the Crystal .Net runtime engine, and you have no business downvoting answers. It is a KNOWN FACT that garbage collection must be called on the report object after it is disposed because it does not get cleaned up fast enough otherwise.

Comment: If it's a "known fact", then make it known here, to the users of [so]. Show what you're talking about. Share the knowledge. Link to the documentation that discusses this "known fact".